# Has anyone figured out how to scale Amazon RDS read replicas?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, replication, amazon-rds

I've recently set up a read replica to take some of the read load off of my Amazon multi-AZ RDS instance.  The Amazon documentation clearly states that it is "up to your application to determine how read traffic is distributed across your read replicas".

Has anyone figured out a manageable way to scale read replicas?  It doesn't seem like a very extensible solution to have different parts of my application hard-coded to read from specific replicas.  Is there a way to set this up that is analogous to putting EC2 instances behind a load balancer?

Comment: I'd recommend looking into [ProxySQL](https://proxysql.com/). It should do exactly what you need! HAProxy is another option, but Proxy SQL will "work better" in practice since it is SQL-aware (HAProxy is not)

Answer (score 7):

An AWS engineer provided some insight into the question [here](http://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-way-to-distribute-read-traffic-among-Amazon-RDS-read-replicas).

Here is a snippet of his response:

> in general you can load-balance traffic at the following 3 logical places:
>
> - Application layer - create multiple connection pools and send all reads to the read-replicas.
> - Web framework/middleware - some web frameworks have in-built support for multiple databases [1].
> - External proxy - You can use an external proxy like MySQLproxy [2].
>
> [1] - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/
>
> [2] - https://launchpad.net/mysql-proxy

Answer (score 6):

I think [HAProxy](http://cbonte.github.com/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html) would be a good option to load balance among multiple read replicas. You can have a config something like this:

```
 listen mysql-cluster 0.0.0.0:3306
     mode tcp
     balance roundrobin
     option mysql-check user root

     server db01 x.x.x.x:3306 check
     server db02 x.x.x.x:3306 check
     server db03 x.x.x.x:3306 check
```

where x.x.x.x is the replica endpoint.

Answer (score 3):

I've been messing with using Route 53 weighted CNAME to load balance RDS read replicas (and the source). I currently have 3 CNAME record sets for readdb.example.com.

The first points to the source db at db.example.com. This is in case there's a replication error. The application can fallback to the original database for reads. Or if you want, you can have the source carry some proportion of the read load, depending on how you set the weight. The Routing Policy is set to Weighted. I have the weight for the source set to 1, so it takes on a very small burden of the read load. The TTL is set low. I've tried values from 1 to 10. I've left it at 10 for now. You also have to enter a Set ID which is any unique string ("Source Database").

The second record set points to one of the read replicas (readdb1.blahblah.rds.amazonaws.com). Routing Policy is weighted, and TTL is 10 like before. It also needs a unique Set ID. I set the weight for this one between 5-50, depending. This one, I do associate with a health check, which you have to create ahead of time. You can probably use a simple healthcheck that points to the replica, but I did something a little different.

I put a file like this on each of my application servers (I'm using PHP Elastic Beanstalk, but you could do something similar in other setups/languages I assume):

```
<?php if($instanceid = $_GET["id"]): ?>
<?php
exec("aws rds describe-db-instances --db-instance-identifier " . escapeshellarg($instanceid), $rdsinfo);
$rdsinfo = implode(' ',$rdsinfo);
$rdsinfo = json_decode($rdsinfo, true);
if($rdsinfo["DBInstances"][0]["StatusInfos"][0]["Normal"] && $rdsinfo["DBInstances"][0]["DBInstanceStatus"] === "available"){
    echo "GOOD!";
    }
else {
    echo "BAD!";
    };
/* Then there's some other stuff in here that is a little unrelated to the question */
?>
<?php endif ?>
```

This file uses the AWS command line interface which is installed on Elastic Beanstalk applications and only requires that the environmental variables for AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_DEFAULT_REGION, and AWS_SECRET_KEY be specified ahead of time. So then you make a Route 53 health check that points to http://www.example.com/rdshealthcheck/rdsshealthcheck.php?id=readdb1 . You set the search string to "GOOD!" I think a search string costs $1/month/health check, which seems reasonable.

If you have a second read replica, you can create another healthcheck that points to http://www.example.com/rdshealthcheck/rdsshealthcheck.php?id=readdb2 or whatever it's called.

I actually only use one read replica at this time, but it is significantly larger than my source db. It was more economical for me, because my source DB is multi-az. I keep the third record set and second health check around in case the first replica is giving me problems. That way, I don't have to wait for the first one to delete before relaunching it. Instead, I immediately delete the first one and launch the second one using the name specified in the third recordset (and second health check).

Comment: What happens when a replica goes down? With a TTL of 10, doesn't that mean that DNS will still respond to clients with the IP of the offline server? (If I'm interpreting your answer right, the healthcheck will disable that replica in Route53, but we'll still have 10 minutes before clients see that change)

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to suggest more convience approach. 
Which is, [DNS Round-robin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_DNS) with [Amazon Route 53](http://aws.amazon.com/route53/).

As you can see in the this [article](http://www.think-lamp.com/2012/12/weighted-round-robin-dns-for-route53/),
[Amazon Route 53](http://aws.amazon.com/route53/) can do Round-robin with multiple CNAMEs.

Then all you need to do is

1. "Creating Record Sets" at Route 53.
2. Update your config file of your application.

In my case, this approach works fine.

Comment: One thing that concerns me about this approach is that some languages like Java caches DNS resolutions to improve performance which can lead to not having my traffic well balanced to all my read replicas as noted here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsJava/latest/DeveloperGuide/java-dg-jvm-ttl.html

Comment: Unless you have multiple backend instances which will cache different addresses.